# how to find first duplicate item in array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

Hi am trying to find duplicate item in array.

here is my question

> Given a read only array of n + 1 integers between 1 and n, find one number that repeats in linear time using less than O(n) space and traversing the stream sequentially O(1) times.
>
> - Input : `[3 4 1 4 1]`
> - ouput : 1
>
> If there are multiple possible answers ( like in the sample case above ), output any one.
>   If there is no duplicate, output -1

```js
let repeatedNumber = function(A) {
  let result = -1
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (A[Math.abs(A[i]) - 1] < 0) {
      result = i
      break
    } else {
      A[Math.abs(A[i]) - 1] = -A[Math.abs(A[i]) - 1]
    }

  }
  return ++result

}

// working fine..!!
console.log(repeatedNumber([3, 4, 1, 4, 1]))
// output 4 is equal to expected output
// fail test case
console.log(repeatedNumber([247, 240, 303, 9, 304, 105, 44, 204, 291, 26, 242, 2, 358, 264, 176, 289, 196, 329, 189, 102, 45, 111, 115, 339, 74, 200, 34, 201, 215, 173, 107, 141, 71, 125, 6, 241, 275, 88, 91, 58, 171, 346, 219, 238, 246, 10, 118, 163, 287, 179, 123, 348, 283, 313, 226, 324, 203, 323, 28, 251, 69, 311, 330, 316, 320, 312, 50, 157, 342, 12, 253, 180, 112, 90, 16, 288, 213, 273, 57, 243, 42, 168, 55, 144, 131, 38, 317, 194, 355, 254, 202, 351, 62, 80, 134, 321, 31, 127, 232, 67, 22, 124, 271, 231, 162, 172, 52, 228, 87, 174, 307, 36, 148, 302, 198, 24, 338, 276, 327, 150, 110, 188, 309, 354, 190, 265, 3, 108, 218, 164, 145, 285, 99, 60, 286, 103, 119, 29, 75, 212, 290, 301, 151, 17, 147, 94, 138, 272, 279, 222, 315, 116, 262, 1, 334, 41, 54, 208, 139, 332, 89, 18, 233, 268, 7, 214, 20, 46, 326, 298, 101, 47, 236, 216, 359, 161, 350, 5, 49, 122, 345, 269, 73, 76, 221, 280, 322, 149, 318, 135, 234, 82, 120, 335, 98, 274, 182, 129, 106, 248, 64, 121, 258, 113, 349, 167, 192, 356, 51, 166, 77, 297, 39, 305, 260, 14, 63, 165, 85, 224, 19, 27, 177, 344, 33, 259, 292, 100, 43, 314, 170, 97, 4, 78, 310, 61, 328, 199, 255, 159, 185, 261, 229, 11, 295, 353, 186, 325, 79, 142, 223, 211, 152, 266, 48, 347, 21, 169, 65, 140, 83, 156, 340, 56, 220, 130, 117, 143, 277, 235, 59, 205, 153, 352, 300, 114, 84, 183, 333, 230, 197, 336, 244, 195, 37, 23, 206, 86, 15, 187, 181, 308, 109, 293, 128, 66, 270, 209, 158, 32, 25, 227, 191, 35, 40, 13, 175, 146, 299, 207, 217, 281, 30, 357, 184, 133, 245, 284, 343, 53, 210, 306, 136, 132, 239, 155, 73, 193, 278, 257, 126, 331, 294, 250, 252, 263, 92, 267, 282, 72, 95, 337, 154, 319, 341, 70, 81, 68, 160, 8, 249, 96, 104, 137, 256, 93, 178, 296, 225, 237]))
// output 327 is equal to expected output 73
```

my approach

I am making index `negative` so that when I am iterating  index `positive index is my dublicate item`

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing at all. Why are you using elements of the array as array indexes?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes.it is not permitted..my mistake

Comment: It looks fine except for the `return ++result`. If there is no duplicate in the array you'll be retuning `0` not `-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it'd be a lot simpler to use a Set or object that keeps track of the elements found so far. When a repeat element is found, return it:

```js
let repeatedNumber = function(A) {
  const set = new Set();
  for (const item of A) {
    if (set.has(item)) return item;
    set.add(item);
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(repeatedNumber([3, 4, 1, 4, 1]))
console.log(repeatedNumber([247, 240, 303, 9, 304, 105, 44, 204, 291, 26, 242, 2, 358, 264, 176, 289, 196, 329, 189, 102, 45, 111, 115, 339, 74, 200, 34, 201, 215, 173, 107, 141, 71, 125, 6, 241, 275, 88, 91, 58, 171, 346, 219, 238, 246, 10, 118, 163, 287, 179, 123, 348, 283, 313, 226, 324, 203, 323, 28, 251, 69, 311, 330, 316, 320, 312, 50, 157, 342, 12, 253, 180, 112, 90, 16, 288, 213, 273, 57, 243, 42, 168, 55, 144, 131, 38, 317, 194, 355, 254, 202, 351, 62, 80, 134, 321, 31, 127, 232, 67, 22, 124, 271, 231, 162, 172, 52, 228, 87, 174, 307, 36, 148, 302, 198, 24, 338, 276, 327, 150, 110, 188, 309, 354, 190, 265, 3, 108, 218, 164, 145, 285, 99, 60, 286, 103, 119, 29, 75, 212, 290, 301, 151, 17, 147, 94, 138, 272, 279, 222, 315, 116, 262, 1, 334, 41, 54, 208, 139, 332, 89, 18, 233, 268, 7, 214, 20, 46, 326, 298, 101, 47, 236, 216, 359, 161, 350, 5, 49, 122, 345, 269, 73, 76, 221, 280, 322, 149, 318, 135, 234, 82, 120, 335, 98, 274, 182, 129, 106, 248, 64, 121, 258, 113, 349, 167, 192, 356, 51, 166, 77, 297, 39, 305, 260, 14, 63, 165, 85, 224, 19, 27, 177, 344, 33, 259, 292, 100, 43, 314, 170, 97, 4, 78, 310, 61, 328, 199, 255, 159, 185, 261, 229, 11, 295, 353, 186, 325, 79, 142, 223, 211, 152, 266, 48, 347, 21, 169, 65, 140, 83, 156, 340, 56, 220, 130, 117, 143, 277, 235, 59, 205, 153, 352, 300, 114, 84, 183, 333, 230, 197, 336, 244, 195, 37, 23, 206, 86, 15, 187, 181, 308, 109, 293, 128, 66, 270, 209, 158, 32, 25, 227, 191, 35, 40, 13, 175, 146, 299, 207, 217, 281, 30, 357, 184, 133, 245, 284, 343, 53, 210, 306, 136, 132, 239, 155, 73, 193, 278, 257, 126, 331, 294, 250, 252, 263, 92, 267, 282, 72, 95, 337, 154, 319, 341, 70, 81, 68, 160, 8, 249, 96, 104, 137, 256, 93, 178, 296, 225, 237]))
```

That takes `O(n)` space though, worst-case.

In the case that there's only one duplicate, you can sum up the total expected of a sequence from 1 to `n` with *no* duplicates. Sum up the input array, and the difference between that and the expected sum is the duplicate number:

```js
let repeatedNumber = function(arr) {
  const expectedLen = arr.length - 1;
  const expected = (expectedLen * (expectedLen + 1)) / 2;
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b) - expected;
}

console.log(repeatedNumber([3, 2, 1, 4, 1]));
console.log(repeatedNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]));
```

If there may be multiple duplicates, one approach is to look at the array like a *graph*, where each element of the array is a pointer to some other element of the array. For example, if the first element is 3, that's a pointer to index 3 of the array. Looking at it this way, finding a repeating element involves finding an index / number which, when looked at [as a graph](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/Functional_graph.svg/330px-Functional_graph.svg.png), is contained in a *cycle* (indicies which, if followed, eventually point back to themselves).

There are a few algorithms for this. One of them is the [tortoise and hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd's_Tortoise_and_Hare) method:

```js
let repeatedNumber = function(A) {
  let slow = A[0];
  let fast = A[A[0]];
  while (slow !== fast) {
    slow = A[slow];
    fast = A[A[fast]];
  }

  fast = 0;
  while (fast !== slow) {
    slow = A[slow]
    fast = A[fast]
  }
  return slow;
}

console.log(repeatedNumber([3, 4, 1, 4, 1]))
console.log(repeatedNumber([247, 240, 303, 9, 304, 105, 44, 204, 291, 26, 242, 2, 358, 264, 176, 289, 196, 329, 189, 102, 45, 111, 115, 339, 74, 200, 34, 201, 215, 173, 107, 141, 71, 125, 6, 241, 275, 88, 91, 58, 171, 346, 219, 238, 246, 10, 118, 163, 287, 179, 123, 348, 283, 313, 226, 324, 203, 323, 28, 251, 69, 311, 330, 316, 320, 312, 50, 157, 342, 12, 253, 180, 112, 90, 16, 288, 213, 273, 57, 243, 42, 168, 55, 144, 131, 38, 317, 194, 355, 254, 202, 351, 62, 80, 134, 321, 31, 127, 232, 67, 22, 124, 271, 231, 162, 172, 52, 228, 87, 174, 307, 36, 148, 302, 198, 24, 338, 276, 327, 150, 110, 188, 309, 354, 190, 265, 3, 108, 218, 164, 145, 285, 99, 60, 286, 103, 119, 29, 75, 212, 290, 301, 151, 17, 147, 94, 138, 272, 279, 222, 315, 116, 262, 1, 334, 41, 54, 208, 139, 332, 89, 18, 233, 268, 7, 214, 20, 46, 326, 298, 101, 47, 236, 216, 359, 161, 350, 5, 49, 122, 345, 269, 73, 76, 221, 280, 322, 149, 318, 135, 234, 82, 120, 335, 98, 274, 182, 129, 106, 248, 64, 121, 258, 113, 349, 167, 192, 356, 51, 166, 77, 297, 39, 305, 260, 14, 63, 165, 85, 224, 19, 27, 177, 344, 33, 259, 292, 100, 43, 314, 170, 97, 4, 78, 310, 61, 328, 199, 255, 159, 185, 261, 229, 11, 295, 353, 186, 325, 79, 142, 223, 211, 152, 266, 48, 347, 21, 169, 65, 140, 83, 156, 340, 56, 220, 130, 117, 143, 277, 235, 59, 205, 153, 352, 300, 114, 84, 183, 333, 230, 197, 336, 244, 195, 37, 23, 206, 86, 15, 187, 181, 308, 109, 293, 128, 66, 270, 209, 158, 32, 25, 227, 191, 35, 40, 13, 175, 146, 299, 207, 217, 281, 30, 357, 184, 133, 245, 284, 343, 53, 210, 306, 136, 132, 239, 155, 73, 193, 278, 257, 126, 331, 294, 250, 252, 263, 92, 267, 282, 72, 95, 337, 154, 319, 341, 70, 81, 68, 160, 8, 249, 96, 104, 137, 256, 93, 178, 296, 225, 237]))
```

Comment: you are using inbuilt `datastructure`

Comment: can we find out using in build `function` and `datastructure`

Comment: You were using the array (well, abusing it as an object) too, which is also a built-in data structure. Are there certain data structures which are forbidden? Which ones *are* permitted?

Comment: in the worst case space of set is `O(n)`

Comment: SEE QUESTION `t repeats in linear time using less than O(n) space `

Comment: I think I have an idea, I'm working on code for it. Though, one oddity: Question says *If there is no duplicate, output -1*, but *Given a read only array of n + 1 integers between 1 and n* there should always be at least one duplicate, I'd think